# Why escape velocity doesnot depend on angle of projection

Tags: gravity

For a projectile projected at a certain angle from horizontal, at the highest point its speed is not equal to zero that means only a part of its initial kinetic energy is utilized to raise the potential energy of earth-body system.
Here is the derivation of escape speed that is given in my book:

Initial K.E. imparted to body to escape earth's gravitation is given by
      $\frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{GM}{R} $
(Here all letters have there usual meaning)

But in case of projectile, only a part of its initial K.E. is utilized.it means that escape speed for a projectile projected at an angle with horizontal should be more than escape speed calculated from above formula.But my book says that escape speed is independent of angle of projection.Why is it so?

Comment: See (https://www.quora.com/Why-does-escape-velocity-not-depend-on-the-angle-of-projection)

Comment: Hi Joey. The question I've linked explains why the escape **speed** doesn't depend on direction. It's because energy is a scalar not a vector.

Comment: @john Rennie That I understood but when a projectile is fired only a certain fraction of its initial KE is used up as the projectile still has som velocity.So wouldnt escape speed more in case when body is fired at an angle

Comment: A projectile fired at escape velocity has zero velocity at infinity. **All** of its kinetic energy is used up escaping from the gravitational field. That's how escape velocity is defined. If only part of the KE was used escaping then the velocity would be greater than the escape velocity.

Comment: @John Rennie is this true even in a non conservative field?